# random numbers using random.randint

Tags: python, list, random, numbers

I have this code to where I am trying to generate ten random numbers. It does generate ten random numbers, but also ten lines of the same numbers.
I am trying to get it to where it only generates ten random number on one line.

here is my code:

```
import random

number_list=[]

for count in range(10):
    number=random.randint(1,100)

    number_list.append(number)

for numbers in number_list:
    print(number_list)
```

Comment: Why are you printing the whole `number_list` once for each item in it? Get rid of the second `for` loop, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: By the way to generate 10 unique random numbers it's better to use `random.sample`:  `random.sample(xrange(1, 100), 10)`

Answer (score 0):

To print the array:

```
print(numbers_list)
```

Comment: This will print one number on ten lines. How can you print ten numbers on one line?

Comment: @Kevin What about this.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Ive tried that. all I get is one number repeated 10 times on its own line, rather than 10 different numbers.

Comment: @YumiTawo could not replicate; I get e.g. `[73, 6, 7, 70, 9, 98, 41, 56, 55, 93]`, as expected

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you guys for your responses. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You were actually running the second for loop to print which would print the same list for ten times.

```
import random

number_list=[]

for count in range(10):
    number=random.randint(1,100)
    number_list.append(number)
print number_list
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join` and `map` function for that :

```
','.join(map(str,number_list))
```

Demo :

```
>>> ','.join(map(str,[1,2,3,4,5]))
'1,2,3,4,5'
```

Comment: You should edit and improve your previous answer, rather than adding another (also: test your answers before posting them).

Comment: yes you are right ! but i had same problem before and after refining the false answer downvoters dont remove their down votes !!

Comment: So be more careful, posting correct answers first time rather than trying to be the [fastest gun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-gun) and missing.

Comment: yes ! im agree with this ! so occasionally i have been notice this bad threat ! maybe its because of that began to answering near 2-3 month ! any way thanks for advanced ! <3

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
for count in range(10):
    number=random.randint(1,100)

    number_list.append(number)

for numbers in number_list:
    print(numbers),
```